# Trying to build qgis - set path to Bison and flex?

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to follow (probably very good) step by step instructions for building QGIS in a Windows environment hence I've got some difficulties to understand where I shall set the paths for Bison and flex in CMAKE and where do I find the option BINDINGS_GLOBAL_INSTALL?

I've uploaded a print screen from my CMAKE
[image: Error message]

The C compiler identification is unknown

The CXX compiler identification is unknown

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (PROJECT):

No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (PROJECT):

No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Windows installer for the trustworthy pre-compiled Windows binaries?  I'm curious because, unless you have a very special reason, you could save yourself considerable trouble (like this for instance).

Comment: *Using* QGIS is a GIS SE question. *Compiling* QGIS is more of a [so] question. Make sure you include the error message(s) as text so that they're both legible and searchable.

Comment: I want to compile QGIS in order to work with the master source and the python3 bindings (I've developed one plugin that I'm intend to publish with QGIS3). I thought it was relevant to post here since it relevant to QGIS? I'll  update the text with the Error messages.